# Mouse over popup like addthis and sharethis?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

does any one know how to create a mouse over popup like addthis.com and sharethis.com?? it should popup exactly on a button. and moreover it does not have anything inserted into Head tag.can be attached javascript with that link between body tag but not in head.

any Ideas, Sample code??

Comment: Addthis and sharethis use javascript. this means you can view source of the websites using it and see the exact code (no sample code necessary).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the drop down menu then this is it.

```
<div id="menu">
  <div id="label">
     Share It!
  </div>
  <div id="list">
       <div>Item 1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#list').hide();
  $('#label').hover(function (){
      $('#list').show(500);
    },function(){
      $('#list').hide(0);
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Put that any where and a menu like will come up copy and paste "item 1" if you need more and you can customise it as well. If you don't know how to do it. I would suggest you start studying HTML,CSS, and JavaScript and finally JQuery a little more.